# Zitadel create service users dinamically

Tags: authentication, user-interface, session

I'd like to implement a feature, in which service users could be created programatically. For example, on my backend on an endpoint I receive the necessary credentials, then I create a service user on Zitadel.

Going through the docs I have only found how to register a human user, but nothing about service users. Is it possible? I have not found an endpoint for this between the API endpoints listed here: https://zitadel.com/docs/category/apis/resources/user_service/user-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking everything you can do in the console is also available in the APIs, and even more.

The service user reference is here:
https://zitadel.com/docs/category/apis/resources/mgmt/user-machine

You need to use the Management API to create new service users: https://zitadel.com/docs/apis/resources/mgmt/management-service-add-machine-user

The necessary steps to do that are:

1. Create a service user (via console)
2. Assign the service user a Manager role
3. Authenticate the service user and request a token
4. Call the Management API with the token to create subsequent service users

ZITADEL offers multiple authentication methods for service users. If you want to get started quickly, you can use a personal access token: https://zitadel.com/docs/guides/integrate/pat

You can also authenticate service users with client credentials (https://zitadel.com/docs/guides/integrate/client-credentials) and private key JWT (https://zitadel.com/docs/guides/integrate/private-key-jwt) for more security. We're currently working on an overhaul of the docs to make those parts a bit easier.

Comment: Ooh, I was looking for this under v2 docs, as I have been following the create your own UI page. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Sure! All functionality from v1 is still not fully migrated to v2, hopefully this will be done in the coming weeks.